# Can't access Kibana in browser (ELK 8.2)

Tags: elasticsearch, cloud, kibana, elk

I'm trying to set up an ELK stack on a remote Oracle Cloud server, but I can't access kibana from a browser. Installation using deb package. The version of elasticsearch and kibana I'm installing is 8.2 (in this version, security settings are already enabled by default, including settings and generation of security certificates) - the latest version for now. I perform the installation according to the instructions from the official site, but nothing is said there about the remote access settings.

I tried to change the settings in the `kibana.yaml` file, uncommented the `"server.port: 5601"` field and edited `server.host: "my ip"` (I also tried `server.host: "0.0.0.0"`), but this does not help .

I also tried to access from the network directly to elasticsearch. I edited its configuration in a similar way, but it did not help. In my case, access to elasticsearch from the network is not essential, but I would also like to get it.

I know that Oracle servers by default have restrictions on the forwarded traffic, so I unblocked the elastic and kibana ports (9200 and 5601) in the Oracle control panel.

I also allowed `ports 9200 and 5601` through ipitables. The UFW firewall is by default in the "inactive" status. When checked through nmap, both ports return a "filtered" status.

Please help fix the issue. I'm just doing a standard installation according to the instructions and I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: what do your Elasticsearch and Kibana logs show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting up a reverse proxy nginx so that it redirects requests coming to the server to `localhost:5601`. These two articles helped me, I hope it helps someone else:

1. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04
2. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elastic-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04-ru (step 2)